# Get all values for A variable in a class

Tags: c#

I have two classes one of them is Destinations and the other one is DestinationDetails

```
public class Destinations
{
    public Destinations() { }

    public string CarrierName { get; set; }

    public List<DestinationDetails> Details { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationDetails
{
    public DestinationDetails() { }

    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

I want to get all `string "Destination"` in the second class from List of objects from the first class

I have `List<Destinations>` and I don't want to use `for loop or foreach` statments

Comment: Get? As in? What have you tried? Currently, it's like you only want a `foreach(DestinationDetails detail in MyDestination.Details) { detail.Destination... }`

Comment: How does your desired output look like?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on my understanding of your question, please check if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @PSCoder you were faster than me in posting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var dest = new Destinations();

//Initialize the details

var destNames = dest.Details.Select(d => d.Destination).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
     var det = new Destinations();
     det.Details = new List<DestinationDetails>();
      det.Details.Add(new DestinationDetails() { Destination = "CA" });
      det.Details.Add(new DestinationDetails() { Destination = "NJ" });
      ...
      ...
     var details = new DestinationDetails();
     details.Destination = string.Join(",",det.Details.Select(x => x.Destination).ToArray() );
```

### Update:-

provided list of Destinations "allDet", you can get the list of strings as below:-

```
  alldet.Where(x => x.Details != null).SelectMany(x => x.Details.Select(y => y.Destination)).ToList() //With out ToList() it will give you IEnumerable<String>
```

Comment: The second Select is Select not SelectMany because each Details has only one Destination

Comment: Right in that case no need of second selectMany

Answer (score 0):

`List<Destinations> AirportDestinations ;` // this list has `Destinations` objects which have `Details` which have `Destination`

So by using `SelectMany`

```
List<string> cities.AddRange(AirportDestinations.Where(x => x.Details != null).SelectMany(d => d.Details.Select(s => s.Destination)));
```

Now you have all `Destination` in all objects in the list